# Laravel - Custom User Fields

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to add custom user fields, but not have them be assigned at registration or "required". Would the most effective way to do this be adding a field to the Auth object, or would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: You can write a migration to add those fields as nullable terms. And let user fill them later after registration

Comment: @VishalSh So I would modify the user model in order to include these and set these through queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fresh Laravel 5 installation you have to edit the User class and the users migration:

1) In your `app/User.php` you have to extend the `$fillable` array for each custom field.

Example: `$fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'city'];` for a custom `city` field.

2) In your `database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` you have to add a database column for each custom field and run afterwards `php artisan migrate` (see http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations).

Example: `$table->string('city');` for a custom `city` field.